# Remove shadow between cards on same elevation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview

Given the following composable

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 32.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium.copy(
            bottomStart = CornerSize(0),
            bottomEnd = CornerSize(0)
        )
    ) {}
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium.copy(
            all = CornerSize(0)
        )
    ) {}
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium.copy(
            topStart = CornerSize(0),
            topEnd = CornerSize(0)
        )
    ) {}
}
```

[image: card shadow]

Is it possible to remove the shadows/lines between cards shown by the red arrow in the image above so it appears as one long card?

**Edit (Adding Context):**
The above is a very simplified version of the issue.  What I want is a list of cards where each card represents a section.  A section (represented by a card) contains an arbitrary list of items so the card can take up any height (can be more than screen height).  There can also be many sections.  Visually, a single section should be represented by one card.
I have a lazy column that cycles through the items and generates appropriate UI except for having the shadow/lines between items in a single card (see image below)

[image: sections]

Comment: Is there a reason it can't be one card?

Comment: That's practically what you want it to be. If you want it to look like a single card, why no simply just make it one? Anyway, if there's something "forcing" you to implement this, it's always good to share the **use-case**. Maybe we can tell you a much better way to achieve what you wish for here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I have updated the question to include context.

Comment: Would putting the LazyColumn inside the card and using a different component for the items work?

Comment: Or try setting the card border, elevation, and `LazyColumn`'s content spacing to zero `dp`s.

Comment: @DanHarms Putting lazy column inside card doesn't work because a single card only represents a single section.  There are multiple sections, the data structure is a list of lists so the lazy column would need to be able to recycle each section as well as each item.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper That is similar to just setting the background as a surface.  I have a workaround where I can draw a background behind each item and that works fine except it uses borders.  Ideally, I would like to use elevation so proper shadows show for each section.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but there is nothing in your requirements that forces the items to be in cards, just the outer section.

Comment: Is it actually the same as surface because I doubt it. You are saying that ALL the methods I just posted above produce the exact replica of just putting the LazyColumn in a surface?

Comment: @DanHarms Yes, only outer sections need to be cards but since each section contains an unknown number of items and there is an unknown number of sections.  I would need a lazy column for each.  Using the image above - I can put lazy column inside a card and get something similar to "1st section",  how would I show "second section" in that case?  Sorry,  maybe i'm undestanding you incorrectly.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper I didn't mean it's the same as putting a lazy column on a surface.  I meant it would be the same as putting the item inside a surface.  I can set the elevation to 0 but then doesn't produce a shadow, the card has a border stoke of `null` by default and content padding of 0 in lazy column still shows that lines between each item.  I'm guessing that line is generated by the elevation since setting the elevation to 0 does get rid of it but then I lose the outer section shadow as well.

Comment: Oh, easy fix. Just make sure horizontal padding on the items is 0.dp, then set the elevation on the column itself while keeping elevations of the children zero.  If I still misunderstood, a prototype of your required layout would be helpful. You can use [Figma](https://www.figma.com/downloads/) for prototyping in general.

Comment: Add `elevation = 0.dp`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That removes the shadow from the outer layer as well which I want to keep.  The reason I initially asked this question was because putting two items at the same elevation should not result in them casting a shadow on each other.  For example in the xml layout, putting 2 cards would not generate a shadow between the cards since they are at the same elevation with no gap in between.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper I have created a sample with full implementation https://github.com/nak411/AndroidComposeCards/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/composewithcards/CardSectionActivity.kt

Comment: Gif showing desired ui  (still has lines in between items) https://github.com/nak411/AndroidComposeCards/blob/main/gifs/ui.gif

Comment: I don't see any lines in the gif. Is that the exact layout you want?

Comment: The lines are there but the gif is low resolution so you don't see it.  It is the same layout.  The image posted in the question is a blown-up high res version of the same layout with it's width adjusted.

Comment: @Naveed did you find solution for above problem, I'm trying to achieve something similar :(

if you have answer please update here.